# CAS Clustering 3.4.11 version

Tags: java, spring, cas

I'm just asking more informaction about clustering CAS in 3.4.11 version.

At the moment I am using DefaultTicketSystem which stores Tickets in-memory.

Moreover, the architecture gonna be - Loader -> 4 working nodes.

I'm currently new to CAS, but have to make some changes. I have to create a CLUSTER on 3.4.11 CAS version, as i know, in-memory ticketing saving system have to be changed to saving to cloud or database from where CLUSTER can access them.

I would like to ask if it's possible to get some more details on how to program cluster, would be perfect to get detailed documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I learnt more about CAS clustering, the main procedure is ticket sharing. So, I had to use it. I was using memcached and it solved my problem. My CAS clients do know about each other and everytime there is a new login, other clients gets that shared ticket to know.